# when fetch data from parse that time progressbar stopped

Tags: android, progress-bar

I am fetching the data from parse in `findInBackground()` method. I want to make the progressbar invisible when all data are fetched and show the `ListView`, but in this code progressbar invisible properly but progressbar stopped. I want to continue progressbar when all the data does not fetch from database.

```
Listuser = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listUser);
    pbLoading = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pbLoading);

    pbLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Listuser.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    cuserlist.add(ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
    query.orderByDescending("point");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
        public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                for (final ParseObject object : objects) {
                    String user = object.getString("username").toString();
                    ParseFile pimage = object.getParseFile("image");
                    // Log.e("without user", String.valueOf(user));
                    list.add(user);
                    int pos = list.indexOf(user);
                    System.out.println("The index of User is: " + pos);

                    userlist.add(user);
                    Bitmap bmp = null;
                    URL img_value = null;
                    try {
                        img_value = new URL(pimage.getUrl());
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                                .permitAll().build();
                        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
                        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(img_value.openConnection()
                                .getInputStream());
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    image.add(bmp);
                    currentRank.add(String.valueOf(pos + 1));

                    pbLoading.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    Listuser.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    final CustomUser adapter = new CustomUser(
                            getActivity(), userlist, image, currentRank);
                    Listuser.setAdapter(adapter);

                }
            } else {

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please confirm which programming language it is and add the relevant tag

Comment: android and see the tag

Comment: Thank you when I reviewed the question it only had "progress-bar", not it will be easier for people to help :)